# Disabling boost for a custom package

Tags: ros, boost, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am new to ros.

I am trying to create a rospkg for the bumblebee XB3 camera from point grey.

I have followed all the documentation for creating a package and so on.

Problem is, i must use a closed library from point grey (triclops). This library uses multi thread and i think there is a problem with the ros cmake, namely on the boost options.

Basically, if i mannually compile a code (using g++ test.cpp -o test) it runs fine but if i compile using ros cmake it seg faults.

I experimented a bit and found that if i manually remove boost from the compilation line it works.

So my question is if there is someway of saying in the CMakeList.txt file that no boost libs are to be used.

Best regards

Miguel Oliveira

University of Aveiro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9955/disabling-boost-for-a-custom-package/) by [migueloliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/530/migueloliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2011-05-13

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just in case someone else stumples upon this... I  ran into a similar problem. For me triclops always seg faulted in *triclopsStereo*. *triclopsRectify* did work (which uses the internal calibration of the bumblebee, that is why I wanted to use it). So I get the rectified images from triclops and passed them to an OpenCV StereoBM block matcher.

```
triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_RIGHT, &image_right );
triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_LEFT, &image_left );

cv::Mat img_r(480,640,CV_8UC1,image_right.data);
cv::Mat img_l(480,640,CV_8UC1,image_left.data);
   
block_matcher_(img_l,img_r,disparity);
```

This gives me real nice disparity images, seemingly even faster than triclops without any hastle of calibration or similar and without crashes, as it seems until now. :)

---

Originally posted by [Achim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1188/achim/) with karma: 390 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is rosbuild_add_boost_directories() which should add boost. But I guess you do not have this commented in.
Do you use any other ROS includes in your programm that in turn might include boost?

If you change CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE to true in build/CMakeCache.txt you can check the exact compilation that is exectued.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using roscpp you cannnot just remove boost.  It's heavily integrated into the functionality of the library.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

a different solution to your problem might be to read the camera with libdc1394. point grey actually advices you to do so(http://www.ptgrey.com/support/kb/index.asp?a=4&q=26). for the bumblebee 2 there is a package (named bumblebee2 (http://www.ros.org/wiki/bumblebee2) that can be used as a reference if you desire to write your own node.

---

Originally posted by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) with karma: 241 on 2011-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1